# Select sets to create a complete list

Tags: python, list, set, unique

I want to create a complete list with given sets. I have several sets in my solution like:

```
set1: [1,2,5,7]
set2: [3,4,6]
set3: [7]
set4: [1,2]
set5: [3,4,7]
set6: [3,6]
```

The goal is to select sets to create a list with all numbers from 1 to 7. If it is not possible, create maximum coverage. For example;

```
set1+set2 = 100%
set1+set5 = 85%
set2+set3+set4 = 85%
```

Above is an example. I need to write an algorithm to find the best sets because I will have at least 1000 different sets. Could you help to find a solution? Thanks

Comment: I'm not really sure I understood what you wanted to achieve, but you may want to take a look at the union set method, which is used to combine set

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `set.union` function. Here are a few examples:

```
>>> set1 = set([1,2,5,7])
>>> set2 = set([3,4,6])
>>> set3 = set([7])
>>> set4 = set([1,2])
>>> set5 = set([3,4,7])
>>> set6 = set([3,6])
>>> len(set.union(set1, set2)) / 7 * 100
100.0
>>> len(set.union(set1, set5)) / 7 * 100
85.71428571428571
>>> len(set.union(set2, set3, set4)) / 7 * 100
85.71428571428571
```

Comment: I need an algorithm to select sets. Function is easy. By the way thanks for your answer

Comment: @SelçukKeskin Please edit your question as it is not clear what you want